# Loopback framework always expecting the input field names as lowercase

Tags: loopbackjs

We are implementing the Database connector with Loopback framework. Database fields are case-insensitive.  Loopback framework creating the model with all table fields and properties as lowercase characters. When we invoke create or update operation with field names as uppercase, it's throwing the input validation errors.

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "status": 422,
    "message": "The `TEST5` instance is not valid. Details: `name` can't be blank (value: undefined).",
    "statusCode": 422,
    "details": {
      "context": "TEST5",
      "codes": {
        "name": [
          "presence"
        ]
      },
      "messages": {
        "name": [
          "can't be blank"
        ]
      }
    },
    "stack": "ValidationError: The `TEST5` instance is not valid. Details: `name` can't be blank (value: undefined).\n    at ..node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\dao.js:211:16\n    at ModelConstructor. (..node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\validations.js:462:11)\n
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .observe with "before save" hook. Then loop through properties converting to lower case. Before save with observe hits before validation too